# when click on a node how to open child node of a child

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

i have a four node tree.I want to click on the second node and want to open directly the fourth node.
Mean i want to open child of the child node.
I am trying it but cant get it.

Comment: suppose :i have four nodes a(root node),b,c,d(last node).
my structure is like  a=>b=>c=>d. Here i want that when i click on "b" i want to open "c" and "d" both. should open "c" and "d" on click on "b".   b=>c=>d.

Comment: Include a code snippet or jsfiddle of what you have tried

Comment: this is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5dsnucue/1/  i want that when i click on second level node it should directly open 4th level node.

Comment: are you getting my point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/5dsnucue/2/

```
//Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
   // show is true if children currently hidden
   var show = !d.children; 
   showKids (show, d); // set the visibility of this node's kids

    // if on second level node and we want to show children of children
    // (don't need to same for hide, hiding intermediate node will do the job)
   if (d.depth === 1 && show) {
        var arr = d.children || d._children;
      // loop through kids and set them to visible
      arr.forEach (function(child) {
        showKids (true, child);
      })
   }
   update(d);
}

// showKids replaces simple toggle with a show parameter
function showKids (show, d) {
  if (!show) {
         d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
      } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          // blank this line as calling showKids with show=true
          // twice in a row will end up nulling .children and ._children
          // so keep d._children populated.
          //
          // Same doesn't apply to the 'if' condition above as we don't
          // pursue hiding down the tree.
          //d._children = null; 
     }
}
```

This lets you do the following behaviour:

1. Click on 2nd level node, 3rd and 4th level nodes are shown
2. Click again on 2nd level node, 3rd and 4th level nodes are hidden
3. Click again on 2nd level node, 3rd and 4th level nodes are shown
4. Click on 3rd level node, 4th level nodes are hidden
5. Click on 2nd level node, 3rd level node is hidden
6. Click again on 2nd level node, 3rd and 4th level nodes are shown

The above code might seem a bit more complicated than it needs to be, but with a simple toggle step 6 would return to the state of step 4 - i.e. only the 3rd level shown. The logic in the code ensures 4th level nodes are always shown when expanding a 2nd level node regardless of their previous state.

Comment: thanks it working.due to this question stack overflow  banned me to post more questions

Comment: please one thing more.I want to collapse all other nodes when expanding one?when one 2nd  level node expand all others 2nd  level node should collapse